# Make one <div>'s height match another's

Tags: html, css

I want to create a header with 2 `div`s in it. The left `div` needs to be the same height as the right one, but the right one can scale based on its contents.

The left `div`'s contents need to be vertically aligned to the middle.

I tried something like this:

```
<header>
    <div id="test1">
        <div>LOGO</div>
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
        <h1>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can't you just set the height of test1 and test2 to 100% ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell;`

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QTth7/2/)

Edit:

In case if you want [**jQuery Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3k95/) it works on all browsers

Comment: Not supported in older IE versions.

Comment: Yep. My answer might look a bit odd but it works cross browser.

Comment: If you call set the height after the each it will take the largest height from multiple children regardless of order http://jsfiddle.net/omwr0nap/

Answer (score 5):

You can fake this using overflow, padding and margins. It's completely cross browser compatible and doesn't need any JavaScript or anything. Just CSS.  For example:

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;     
}

.test {
    background: red;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/M8msM/11/)**

There is also always faux cols (using a background image) but this is a better method that doesn't need images.

Comment: Would do it with faux columns personally as this seems a bit of a hack, but I like this method.

Comment: I've not put it through a CSS validator to be honest but it's the best x-browser method I've seen. I can't believe the number of people saying jQuery is the best option. Slight overkill.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a bit of javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setHeight($('#test1'), $('#test2'));

  // When the window is resized the height might
  // change depending on content. So to be safe
  // we rerun the function
  $(window).on(resize, function() {
      setHeight($('#test1'), $('#test2'));        
  });

});

// sets height of element 1 to equal the height of element 2
function setHeight(elem1, elem2) {
  var height = elem2.height()
  elem1.css('height', height); 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LyeKj/)**

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: Above code works. Only thing is that console alerts "Uncaught ReferenceError: resize is not defined" - To avoid that: Remove "resize," in above code and it wont show that error.

Answer (score 0):

display: flex;
in the parent container works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33058884)